# Table caption appears inside outline in some browsers, outside in others

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am putting a border and outline around a table. It works fine in latest IE and Firefox, but Chrome is putting the outline around my captions as well. In IE and Firefox the outline only displays around the table, which is what I want. How to fix this in Chrome?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R7aTq/17/

**HTML**

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="homepagemodule  report" id="trades">
    <caption><span>Pending Trades</span></caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Currently Outstanding Trades</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="oddtablerow">
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>0 trades proposed by me to others</li>
                    <li>0 trades proposed by others to me</li>
                    <li><a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=56019&amp;O=05">View trades now</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

Table caption appears inside outline in some browsers, outside in others.

```
caption {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12pt;
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.report {
    width: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an image of what it looks like for you? seems fine to me

Comment: This affects Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

Comment: The decision of whether a table caption should appear inside or outside of a table outline appears to have been left up to individual browsers to choose. It appears to be very consistent for each browser though, and reasonable either way. Personally, I find it more appropriate to have the caption inside the outline, as is the case with Chrome, since the caption is a part of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the `outline` and move it to `tbody`.  Outline is used to show focus on an element, the whole element.  Chrome sees the whole element as `table` which `caption` is a child of so it puts the outline around all of it.

Remove `outline` from your report class and add a new class or new style to `tbody` that sets the outline.

**EDIT**

Add in `display:block;` that seems to fix it.

*updated* the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/R7aTq/83/

Or you could get rid of tables all together and use divs like in this fiddle:

*non-table version*: http://jsfiddle.net/R7aTq/130/

Comment: The styling isn't the same. There's no longer a 2px gap between the outline and the background color (the white border inside the outline).

Comment: thx , i tried the tbody before posting and didn't work in Chrome

Comment: Jake retried again, it works in Chrome now, but leaves a larger outline in FF and IE   http://jsfiddle.net/R7aTq/80/

Comment: Jake looks good in IE, Chrome and FF , i don't have Safari or Opera to check...anyone ?  I see you gave the tbody a class of outline, i retesting using .report>tbody , works fine without having to add that class to all my tables. Thanks ! I tried to mark you up , but says i need 15 reputation here....

Comment: @JakeZeitz: It works fine in Safari and Opera as well. Nice solution!

Comment: @user2200854 you can click the checkmark, no reputation required.

Comment: Jake, while the outline and border work well, using the display:block is not so good on the tables , now no width can be set exampl http://jsfiddle.net/R7aTq/93/

Comment: I hate working with tables, so try messing with the non-table version that I added in the answer.

Comment: @JakeZeitz: It's worth mentioning that this isn't the type of content that's really appropriate for an HTML table anyways. Tables are best used for data grids. Arguably, little or nothing is gained by using a table here.